# What does vector space and bra/ket space mean?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space

I wonder What are the similarities and dissimilarities between a [vector space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space) and [bra/ket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bra%E2%80%93ket_notation) space?

Comment: Do you mean a [Hilbert space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space) by bra/ket space?

Comment: Nothing stops you from using a finite dimensional normed vector space in <bra|ket> notion, which is really just physicists making up a new way of writing a norm and a scalar product. A general Hilbert space takes that to the level of infinite many dimension, in which case one also needs completeness, so that limits are defined and the usual operations of calculus can be introduced.

Comment: bra-ket is a *notation* for vector spaces:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bra%E2%80%93ket_notation#Ket_notation_for_vectors

Answer (score 4):

Per the linked wikipedia article, vector spaces are linear mathematical structures satisfying the axioms of a vector space.

Bras and kets are vectors of a specific type of complex vector space called a Hilbert space.  The Hilbert space is additionally defined by the following inner product, which must be finite:

$<b|k> = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} b(x)^* k(x) dx$

Where $b(x)^*$ denotes of the complex conjugate of the vector $b(x)$.

Bras are row vectors, where kets are column vectors.  Taking the complex transpose of a ket will give you a bra, and vice versa.